# Forbidden Access on this server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to populate a dropdown on document ready using AJAX.

However I cannot access my Supplies_controller because I am forbidden.

My populate_dropdown.js file is on a different folder than my Supplies_controller file.

This is the error that I've been getting

[image]

This is my code in my populate_dropdown.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo base_url('Supplies_controller/getCategory'); ?>",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
           $(data).each(function(){
               $("#category").append($('<option>', {
                   value: this.id,
                   text: this.category,
               }));
           })
       }
   });
});
```

This is the code in my Supplies_controller

```
<?php
class Supplies_controller extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->model('supplies_model');
}

public function getCategory(){
    $categories = $this->supplies_model->getCategory();
    echo json_encode($categories);
}

public function getSubcategory(){
    $category_id = $this->input->post('category');
    $subcategories = $this->supplies_model->getSubCategory($category_id);
    echo json_encode($subcategories);   
}

public function getSupply(){
    $subcategory_id = $this->input->post('category');
    $supplies = $this->supplies_model->getSubCategory($subcategory_id);
    echo json_encode($supplies);    
}
```

This is the hierarchy of my files

[image]

My Supplies_controller is inside the controller folder and my populate_dropdown.js file is in inside the js folder.

Please help me find my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: PHP can not be parsed/read/executed in js file. You have to put your js code in view file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a var variable for base_url

For a view file script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";

    $.ajax({
       url: base_url + "supplies_controller/getCategory",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
           $(data).each(function(){
               $("#category").append($('<option>', {
                   value: this.id,
                   text: this.category,
               }));
           })
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

Or for a java script file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
       url: "supplies_controller/getCategory",
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
           $(data).each(function(){
               $("#category").append($('<option>', {
                   value: this.id,
                   text: this.category,
               }));
           })
       }
   });
});
```

On your config.php set your base_url.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';
```

> Note: Make sure your assets folder is out side of application folder.

Comment: The url: "Supplies_controller/getCategory", worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try change this

```
url: "<?php echo base_url('Supplies_controller/getCategory'); ?>",
```

to this

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('Supplies_controller/getCategory'); ?>",
```

ahh i see now you can not run php codes inside javascript. 
if you want base url in javascript you need something like this

```
url: location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/ppmp/index.php/Supplies_controller/getCategory" ,
```

Comment: So I tried this url: location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/index.php/Supplies_controller/getCategory" ,. I'm not getting any error but at the same time I'm not getting any results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy url before include js

```
    <script>
       var URL = "<?php echo base_url('Supplies_controller/getCategory'); ?>";
    </script>
    <script src="populate_dropdown.js"></script>
```

Then in JS file you can use variable URL

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       url: URL,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
           $(data).each(function(){
               $("#category").append($('<option>', {
                   value: this.id,
                   text: this.category,
               }));
           })
       }
   });
});
```